# Java Alter Swing Element from Child Class

Tags: java, swing, class, scope, parent-child

I'm having a problem with something I don't understand. I have a java class that is building up my program and another class full of functions called by action listeners.

I'm hoping to use the the child's class functions to alter the contents of a JLabel (just an example) using a setter function which doesn't seem to be doing anything and not crashing.

My main class has

```
public class Parent extends JFrame {

    static JPanel  dummyPanel  = new JPanel();
    static JLabel  dummyLabel  = new JLabel("label");
    static JButton dummyButton = new JButton("button");
    static Child   child       = new Child();

    public Parent() {

        // main setup goes here

        // add elements goes here

        ActionListener alterLabel = new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent dummyButton) {
                child.childFunc();
            }
        }
        dummyButton.addActionListener(alterLabel);

    }

    // main function goes here

    public void newText() {
        dummyLabel.setText("altered");
        System.out.println("new text function has been executed");
    }

}
```

Then the child I am using to call the function to change the text contains

```
public class Child {

    public void childFunc() {
        Parent parent = new Parent();
        parent.newText();
    }

}
```

When I click the button it runs and I see it outputs the string which I expect but it does not seem to change the label.

Why is this and is there a way to fix it?

Comment: What do you think `Parent parent = new Parent();` is doing? How do you think this will affect the instance of `Parent` which is already visible on the screen? To affect the current instance, you will need to pass a reference of it to `Child`

Comment: I think it's creating a separate instance of the parent class but I'm hoping there's a way around this